# how to reset word sentiment according to the feature?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, wordnet, feature-extraction, sentiment-analysis

For sentiment analysis I am using sentiwordnet 3.0 and it works well in most cases but for some features score should be completely opposite.

For Example : If the topic is "TOY"

```
1) Feature "Quality" - getting correct score

   High quality (+ve score)

   Less quality (-ve score)

2) Feature "Price" - getting wrong score

   High price (+ve score but it should be -ve)

   Less price (-ve score but it should be +ve)
```

Can someone suggest how can we change the polarity of words according to feature ?
Any papers / concepts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, I will rephrase your question to make sure we are on the same page. For the given example, your goal is to assign polarity scores to the words "high" and "less", depending on their context. Whenever "high" refers to quality, you would like to assign it a positive connotation. However, when "high" refers to price, you would like to assign it a negative connotation.

Let's step back for a second and see the bigger picture. You probably have a sentence like "The price of the toy is too high to buy it for my kid.", and you want to figure out whether this is a positive or negative statement. The way you model this problem is to consider that "price" is an attribute for "high". Under this framework, it is a bit hard to reason. I would suggest reversing your view: think about "high" as being an attribute of "price", and aim to change the score of "price" according to whether it is "high" or "low".

Whichever view you choose in the end, the problem reduces to determining a) entities and b) attributes. In my view, "price" is an entity and "high" is its attribute. In yours, "high" is an entity and "price" is an attribute. Either way, you would have to determine pairs of (entity, attribute), and then define a mathematical relation that states in what way the attribute score influences the final score. This is hard mostly because determining entities and attributes is a well-known problem in NLP, and does not have a trivial solution.

What people usually do is use the bag-of-words techniques. This means that you take all the scores of all the words in the sentence, add them up, and them output the final score. It is a bit counter-intuitive, because it discards all the information about the sentence structure, but it works surprisingly well for long enough texts. It is the magic of big numbers -- a good movie review will have enough positive terms to outscore the negative ones.

An alternative is to use machine learning. Instead of worrying yourself how to combine these features, you simply give them to a machine and let a statistical learner infer the best combination. To my knowledge, Stanfard has achieved state-of-the-art performance using a deep recursive network.

I am well aware that this is not the kind of answer that you were expecting, but I wanted to make the point that this is not as easy of a problem as it might seem. A lot of research has gone into language modelling and sentiment analysis, and it turned out that there is very little that you can do manually. By manually I mean reasoning about how to combine scores or performing some kind of if/then/else analysis (e.g. if the word is "high", then if its attribute is "price", then if...)

Comment: Thanks. But my question is how can I determine the polarity of word based on feature. Please see the modified example in Question.

Comment: Your edit makes it a bit clearer, but I'm still not convinced why you consider that "high price" should necessarily be considered negative. For instance, "high price" could have the meaning of "valuable", which is positive.

Comment: Edited example again .. added topic. May be I am making it too specific ... but i need to find some way to detect the sentiments based on topic and its feature.

Comment: In the example above, what is the word that you are predicting the polarity for? Is it the word "toy", which has the following features: {quality, price}? Or is it some other word, with the following features: {topic, quality, price}?

Comment: Words are "high" and "less" for which sentiments to decide... for topic "toy" and features "quality" and "price"